# Создание фейк-класса

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Есть класс, `X` в конструктор надо передать интерфейс. Как я понял можно передать любой класс его реализующий. Но единственный такой класс является абстрактным, причём его наследник тоже один и его экземпляр создать нельзя. А может и можно но я не могу.

Создал собственный класс и наследую его от абстрактного. В конструкторе вызываю конструктор суперкласса. Но вот почему-то все поля класса `X` не инициализируются после создания его экземпляра. Почему?

Классом `X` является `com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.IccCardProxy`.

Мой код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    BaseCommands ci = new FakeCommandsInterface(this);
    IccCardProxy icp = new IccCardProxy(this, ci, 2);
}

public class FakeCommandsInterface extends BaseCommands
{

    public FakeCommandsInterface(Context c){
        super(c);
        UiccController.make(MainActivity.this, new CommandsInterface[]{this});

    }

//overrided methods

}
}
```

Comment: Вполне возможно, что для инициализации `IccCardProxy` нужно, чтобы в каких-то `@Override` методах  происходило и возвращалось что-то осмысленное. А ещё у меня есть большие сомнения, что нужно связываться с `com.android.internal` без веских на то причин. Вам действительно нужно именно с этим классов (и неким `BaseCommands`) работать?

Comment: @Regent, именно с ним. Нужно получить `IccCardProxy`. Кстати `BaseCommands` создаётся корректно, вызываются методы, например, `getRilVersion` возвращает `-1`. Приложение будет огромным проектом, наверное, я первый это сделаю. Нужны методы из `IccCardProxy`. Вскрывал системные приложения, в них вызывается все через этот класс, а именно интересует `supplyDeperdonalization`, для некоторых моделей уже приложение работает, но там реализация другая (запись в системные настройки, отправка АТ-комманд). Сейчас начинаю поддерживать другие модели, в них вот так вот все... Пишу нечто похожее на SuperSU

Comment: Чёрт побери `getRilVersion` возвращает переменную которая иниуиализируется как `-1` без каких либо причин. Значит все-таки я не создаю `BaseCommands`